# SQL data model: How should I store objects (one type) of which some will be shared among all users and some assigned to particular users only?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-modeling

I'm creating data model for `Users` and `Reports` (reports have additionally 1:many relation with `ReportConditions`). My concern is that some reports will be system reports, which means they will be identical for all users except for a few user-related properties (eg. `isHidden` flag assigned by users). Other reports will be custom reports created by users themselves and used by the creator only.

I see 3 options how to tackle the problem. Each has some drawbacks in my opinion. My preference currently is a solution which I consider having least problematic:

1. Have table `Users` linked to `Reports` by 1:many relation. `Reports` table would store both system and custom reports, with the system ones flagged accordingly. For additional properties of system reports I would create an additional join table `SystemUserReports` for many-to-many relation between `Users` and `Reports`. CONS: relations of system and custom reports and data querying need to be handled differently programmatically, eg. `isHidden` property needs to be extracted from `Reports` for custom reports and from `SystemUserReports` for system reports. This does not seem to be a big issue though.

Other options:

2. Store each kind of reports in separate tables: `CustomReports` (1:many with `Users`, 1:many with `CustomReportConditions`) and `SystemReports` (many-to-many with `Users` through `UserSystemReports`, 1:many with `SystemReportConditions`). CONS: 5 tables in total for reports and they store very similar type of data.
3. Store everything in `Reports` related 1:many with `Users` with no additional relations, but clone system reports data for every user. CONS: likely doubling (or more) amount of data in `Reports` and `ReportConditions` tables.

Is my preferred option a right choice from good practices/performance perspective? Or should I expect some problems with this approach and go with one of the others (or some completely different)?

Comment: I see another option: use the `UserReports` JOIN table for **ALL** reports (system and custom) but test for the "System_Reports_Flag" before allowing more than one user record. Also, you can add a column in the JOIN table to indicate which user is the "author" or "controlling user" of the report - if that's useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea. It would certainly improve my initial solution!